# How to use gsub in R for this particular case?

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

`gsub` is a function which allows us to extract and replace patterns in strings but I'm having a hard time trying to understand its underlying logic. For example, I want to extract the last part of these strings (extension):

```
files = c(
  "tmp-project.csv", "project.csv", 
  "project2-csv-specs.csv", "project2.csv2.specs.xlsx", 
  "project_cars.ods", "project-houses.csv", 
  "Project_Trees.csv","project-cars.R",
  "project-houses.r", "project-final.xls", 
  "Project-final2.xlsx"
)

gsub("\\.[a-zA-Z]*$", "\\1" ,files)
```

What I get is anything but the string I want.

```
 [1] "tmp-project"         "project"             "project2-csv-specs" 
 [4] "project2.csv2.specs" "project_cars"        "project-houses"     
 [7] "Project_Trees"       "project-cars"        "project-houses"     
[10] "project-final"       "Project-final2"
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the logic of gsub? I know there is `stringr` package to handle this kind of problems in an easy way but I'm looking for an `R base` solution.
Thank you.

Comment: You use `\1` as the replacement pattern, but have not defined any capturing group in the pattern. `gsub` replaces matches. To extract with `gsub`, you need to match the whole string and capture what you need to keep. So, `gsub(".*\\.([a-zA-Z]*)$", "\\1" ,files)`

Comment: This definetively answers all my questions. Thanks a lot, I had a very bad time struggling with gsub.